# How do I prevent my program from throwing JSON Decode errors?

Tags: python, json, atom-editor

I'm new to python and APIs and I'm using [this](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/last-fm-api-python/) tutorial to learn with last-fm. I'm getting these errors:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vikram03/Desktop/Python_learning/fm.py", line 89, in <module>
    total_pages = int(response.json()['artists']['@attr']['totalPages'])
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Here's the code in question:

```
#initializes reponses list
responses = []

page = 1
total_pages = 70


while page <= total_pages:
    payload = {
        'method': 'chart.gettopartists',
        'limit': 500,
        'page': page
    }

    #print
    print("Requesting page {}/{}".format(page, total_pages))

    #clear clear_output
    clear_output(wait=True)

    #make the API call
    response = lastfm_get(payload)

    #error check
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(reponse.text)
        break

    #extract pagination info
    page = int(response.json()['artists']['@attr']['page'])
    total_pages = int(response.json()['artists']['@attr']['totalPages'])


    # append
    responses.append(response)

    #if its not cached, sleep
    if not getattr(response, 'from_cache', False):
        time.sleep(0.25)

    #increment
    page += 1
```

This function: `lastfm_get` just does `requests.get` with the appropriate params and this url `'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/'`

From other posts I get the impression the program is getting non-JSON objects, but when I print
`total_pages = int(response.json()['artists']['@attr']['totalPages'])` I get the correct number.

edit:
this is the function:M

```
def lastfm_get(payload):
    #define headers and url
    headers = {'user-agent': USER_AGENT}
    url = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/'

    #add API key and format
    payload['api_key'] = API_KEY
    payload['format'] = 'json'

    response = requests.get(url, headers = headers, params = payload)
    return response
```

edit2:

I added this code to check if I was getting a JSON object, and am getting a type error after about 200 pages:

```
#check object
    try:
        json_test = json.loads(lastfm_get(payload))
    except TypeError:
        print("not a json object")
```

Error:

```
Requesting page 256/7743
Requesting page 259/7743
Requesting page 275/7743
Requesting page 294/7743
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vikram03/Desktop/Python_learning/fm.py", line 94, in <module>
    page = int(response.json()['artists']['@attr']['page'])
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I got a type error when I tried with `except ValueError:`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vikram03/Desktop/Python_learning/fm.py", line 84, in <module>
    json_test = json.loads(lastfm_get(payload))
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response
```

EDIT3: I get this error when testing the output of `lastfm_get`:

```
TypeError: Object of type Response is not JSON serializable
```

Unsure how to resolve this.

I'm not sure why the page numbers are skipping either

Comment: Can you provide an example response from `lastfm_get()`? Are you _100% sure_ it's giving you a valid JSON response?

Comment: I added the function. I'm also going to test with .loads

Comment: After about 200 pages it throws a type error

Comment: What is `response.text` when it fails calling `response.json()`?

Comment: I didn't ask for the function. I asked for the _response that is generating the error_. "After about 200 pages it throws a type error "—so what is the problematic response after "about 200 pages"?

Comment: Or even `response.status_code`?  You aren't checking it.  Maybe the response failed.

Comment: Thanks Chris, like you suggested, the response object after x pages is not JSON. Unsure how to resolve
```
TypeError: Object of type Response is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Hi @MarkTolonen, I have an if statement to check if the ''response.status_code" is not 200. Do you suggest I try something else or move that around? Thanks again!

Comment: You could also check `response.headers['Content-Type']` to see what the response type actually is.